# “mexschurfun.mexmaci64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, cvx

I am trying to use CVX in MATLAB, but when I run a my code, I get this error:

> “mexschurfun.mexmaci64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

I have already tried changing my Mac security to "Allow anyway" for the “mexschurfun.mexmaci64” file, but it still gives me the same error. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where did you get this MEX-file from? I presume you didn't build it yourself? If the MEX-file depends on some dynamic library, you will need to allow running that one as well.

Comment: I just downloaded CVX and installed it using the cvx_setup command and got this error: “mexschurfun.mexmaci64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. And then for the other error while running a cvx code. I have no idea what this MEX-files are.

Comment: You might want to try building the MEX-files yourself, if there's source code available. MEX-files are compiled functions in C or C++ or Fortran, that work like any normal MATLAB function.

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is taken directly from the [cvx forum](http://ask.cvxr.com/t/gurobi-mexmaci64-cannot-be-opened-because-the-developer-cannot-be-verified/6755/3).

> This is a problem of the Gatekeeper in macOS. Go to System Preferences/Security & Privacy and then check the option “Anywhere” in “Allow apps downloaded from”. Follow [these instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2016/09/27/allow-apps-from-anywhere-macos-gatekeeper/) if this option is not yet visible.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the source where you have downloaded FieldTrip, you can resolve these errors for all MEX-files at once by opening a terminal and typing

```sh
sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine LOCATION_OF_FIELDTRIP

sudo find LOCATION_OF_FIELDTRIP -name \*.mexmaci64 -exec spctl --add {} \;
```

where `LOCATION_OF_FIELDTRIP` is the place where you have unzipped FieldTrip. Following sudo you will have to give your administrator password.

The first command removes all FieldTrip files from quarantine, the second adds a Gatekeeper exception to all MEX-files.

Check the following link for more help:
https://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/faq/mexmaci64_cannot_be_opened_because_the_developer_cannot_be_verified/